# Will the early access apps be automatically uninstalled when the open test period is over?

Tags: android, google-play

Will the app be automatically uninstalled after the open public test period is over, or is it up to the user to uninstall it?
I am worried if the app contains bugs or problems, the app should be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app will not be automatically uninstalled. You should replace with a higher version code production version which the user will be updated to.